# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express

[image]I am getting this error when ever i am trying to send and recieve data in the same post. im not able to figure out the problem.

But the its not that the code is not working at all, the data's are being displayed perfectly fine. Its just that im getting  this erroe in the bash console.

```
router.post('/add',(req, res) => {

    const newAMCReg = new AMCReg({
      amcrefno: req.body.amcrefno,
      amcregdate: req.body.amcregdate,
      customer: req.body.customerid,
      customertype: req.body.customertypeid,
      department: req.body.customersubdepartmentid,
      serviceprovider: req.body.serviceproviderid,
      amcstartdate: req.body.amcstartdate,
      amcexpiredate: req.body.amcexpiredate,
      remarks: req.body.remarks
    });
    newAMCReg.save()
    .then((amcid) => {

      AMCReg.findOne({amcrefno: req.body.amcrefno})
      .then(amc => res.json(amc))
      .then(amc => {
        res.status(200).json({ msg: "AMC Registration Updated Successfully" });
      })
      .catch(err => res.status(500).json({msg: "Internal Server Error"}));
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not send the response more than once, please see below :

```js
router.post('/add', (req, res) => {

  const newAMCReg = new AMCReg({
    amcrefno: req.body.amcrefno,
    amcregdate: req.body.amcregdate,
    customer: req.body.customerid,
    customertype: req.body.customertypeid,
    department: req.body.customersubdepartmentid,
    serviceprovider: req.body.serviceproviderid,
    amcstartdate: req.body.amcstartdate,
    amcexpiredate: req.body.amcexpiredate,
    remarks: req.body.remarks
  });
  newAMCReg.save()
    .then((amcid) => {

      AMCReg.findOne({
          amcrefno: req.body.amcrefno
        })
        .then(amc => {
          res.status(200).json({
            msg: "AMC Registration Updated Successfully",
            data: amc
          });
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(500).json({
          msg: "Internal Server Error"
        }));
    })
});
```

Comment: How do i do it then i have send and get at the same time. this code is giving me results

Comment: Thanks Vikash it did answer my question, actually i did not see your comment below, tnx. you are awesome!!!